# Vmware not starting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, vmware, virtualization, vmware-player, vmware-workstation

Ubuntu is not running.Vmware shows following context:

```
Setting SATA ALPM on host17 to max_performance...Done
...
...
***sched policy powersave OFF
Setting /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.1 to on
```

How to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**
The problem is solved by following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo service gdm restart
```

Comment: Did you already install it or do you want to boot the ISO in the vm?

Comment: I already installed ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I started by failsafex mode so an error occurred : the system is running low-graphics mode

Comment: Please write an answer to your question and mark it as accepted, instead of changing the title.